# Need to hide bottom bar in tab bar navigation based application

Tags: iphone, ios, tabbar, viewcontroller, navigationbar

I'm having problem in Tabbar-Navigation based application. I have a tab bar with 3 tab bar button items.

Each Tab bar item, I need to show the Navigation controller's view. When I click on the first button, I need to show Navigation controller's root view.

I need that when navigation controller's view is pushed, then in one view I need to show tab bar. When second view is pushed, I need to hide tab bar. When third view is pushed, I need to show tab bar again. It should also work when the view is popped up.

In Navigation controller's root view (Main view), I need to show the tab bar at bottom. But a new view (first view) is pushed then I need to hide the tab bar. Then I have set the property `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to YES.

```
FirstViewController *firstController = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
firstController. hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstController animated:YES];
```

It works fine with the first view.

But the problem is when I push a new view (Second view) , tab bar is not shown even if I set the property:

```
SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
secondController. hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
[self.navigationController secondController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Is this correct ? `[self.navigationController pushViewController:selImageList animated:YES];` Shouldn't it be `firstController  ` instead of `selImageList` ?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23269013/318834

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this works.

```
FirstViewController *firstController = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
//firstController. hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:firstController animated:YES];
```

Comment: NO it's not working bcoz tab bar is shown when first view is displayed. And I need to hide the Tabbar for the first view.