# How to Hide Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uitabbarcontroller, touch

How to Hide Tab Bar Controller ?
I want to hide the Tab Bar controller with double tap on UIImageView.

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36148064/3078925

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this code:

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

where tabbarcontroller is needed to be defined...

**EDIT**

```
AppDelegateFileName *appDelegate = (AppDelegateFileName *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.tabbarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

before doing this make sure that you create a @property declaration of `tabbarController` in appDelegate .h file.

Comment: how can i define tabbarcontroller?

Comment: `UITabbarController *tabbarController;` in .h file and just give `IBOUTLET` in .xib file...

Comment: i declare tabbar controller in app delegate ....
how can i use in myviewcontroller.

Answer (score 13):

If using Storyboards you can simply uncheck a checkbox in your ViewController's Attribute Inspector. It's called "Hide Bottom Bar on Push". Very convenient indeed, and no need to handle the showing of the tabBar again after navigating back from your tabBar-less viewController. I don't know in which XCode-version this was introduced, but it's there for XCode 6 + .

Answer (score 6):

Use Tap Gesture Recognizer to detect double taps on a `UIImageView`. Then invoke a method on detecting the double double tap. Add the following line of code in that method.

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to call tabbar controller in this view?

Comment: what do u mean by call tabbar controller in this view ? Could u pls explain more on that ?

Comment: hiding tabbar is ok, but tab bar space appear black

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan add this line after setting it to hidden: self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;

Answer (score 4):

Use the code below to hide/show tab bar controller in animated style.
`hiddenTabBar` is a `BOOL` variable.

```
- (void) hidetabbar {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];

    for(UIView *view in objtabbar.view.subviews)
    {

        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {

            if (hiddenTabBar) {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            } else {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }
        } else {
            if (hiddenTabBar) {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
            } else {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
            }

        }
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    hiddenTabBar = !hiddenTabBar;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

UIViewController has a property

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UITabBarController *tabBarController
```

which you can set:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.1:

```
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = true
```

Comment: Type safety: `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true`

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you push the view to the new view:

```
self.tabbarconroller.tabbar.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

Swift 3

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

Swift 2

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C

> [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];

Objective-C 2.0

> self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

Swift
before iOS 9

> tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true

Swift iOS 9 and above

> tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

Extra trick with Swift 5 and above: if you would like to change the hidden property then toggle it

```
if let t = tabBarController?.tabBar {
    t.isHidden = t.!isHidden
}
// is equal to 
tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden.toggle()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Solution for multiple root view controllers**

If you or someone would need to hide the tab bar inside a custom controller, for an app that uses multiple `rootViewController` try something like this:

```
//instantiate appDelegate in your controller first
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

//then just hide the tab bar as following
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```