# iPhone: How to hide tab bar to show fullscreen view

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have gallery view in my iphone app. On tap gesture, I am hiding the Navigation bar by:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:activated animated:YES];
```

I have tab bar also, how to hide it and display the image as full screen?

Comment: is it a `UITabBarController` ??? or simple a `UITabBar` ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Hide Tab Bar Controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466829/how-to-hide-tab-bar-controller)

Comment: @InderKumarRathore, it is `UITabBarController`

Answer (score 3):

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
[[self.view.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"layerAnimation"]; 
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];

// Display tab bar animated
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
[[self.view.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"layerAnimation"]; 
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
```

I have not checked this code but I think it will work

Comment: @krishna: I am getting a greyish white bar in the bottom (in the place of tab bar).

Answer (score 2):

```
[[self navigationController] setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
```

i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
this will hide the tabbar
```

Comment: if You want to hide your bottom bar while pushing this will help

Answer (score 0):

If it a `UITabBarController` then it has a property `tabBar`.

```
tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES
```

should work for you.
Also if your image is not a full size  then change the frame of UIImageView to CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460); if you are showing a status bar.

Comment: Getting a white bar in the bottom (in the place of tab bar) which comes on top of the image (even after hiding tab bar & resizing the imageview frame).