# Need to load UIViewController from appdelegate and hide UITabBarController when loaded in Storyboard App

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an app, in that app if its the first time the user has run the app I need to display a welcome screen and then present some 1st time only setup information for the app.  I think the best place to put this is in the appdelegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions), maybe need correction if wrong.  In the app delegate I call this method:

```
-(void) checkSetupOccured
{

    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        //File doesn't exist, first time ran or installed
        UITabBarController *MyTabViewController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        [MyTabViewController setSelectedIndex:3];
        WelcomeHomeViewController *welcomeHomeViewController = [[MyTabViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:3];
        [welcomeHomeViewController viewDidLoad];
        //Need help here I think  - Anyway to hide MyTabViewController when its presented?
     }

}
```

I have been through a lot of threads and the things that keeps popping up are:

```
 //[MyTabViewController presentModalViewController:WelcomeHomeViewController animated:YES];
 //self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
 //[self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
```

I have tried many different places with these and probably just need to step back and relax but I can't find the solution right now.  Also to note **this is not in an UITableView**.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and I always mark my questions answered when answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is what I put in the if statement:

```
    UITabBarController *MyTabViewController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    [MyTabViewController setSelectedIndex:3];
    UINavigationController *welcomeHomeViewController = [[MyTabViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:3];
            UITabBar *tabBar = MyTabViewController.tabBar;
    tabBar.hidden = YES;
    [welcomeHomeViewController viewDidLoad];
```

This does seem off to me, please let me know if there is a better way.  Just wanted to post the answer incase anyone else can be helped from this.

EDIT:The bar is still visible :( , but there are no buttons to push, just a black strip.  Any help would be appreciated.  At least the user can't access the bar, but I need to hide it eventually.

Edit:OK FINALLY!! So glad I have this solved and really hope this can help others!

Here it is, modified in appsdevs post here:
[How to Hide Tab Bar Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466829/how-to-hide-tab-bar-controller/7466975#7466975)

```
UITabBarController *MyTabViewController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    for(UIView *view in MyTabViewController.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } else 
        {
          [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
        }
    }

    [MyTabViewController setSelectedIndex:3];
    UINavigationController *welcomeHomeViewController = [[MyTabViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:3];

    [welcomeHomeViewController viewDidLoad];
```