# how to hide tab bar when push and show tab bar when back

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, tabbar

I want

view controller 1: tab bar is showed

view controller 2: tab bar is showed

view controller 3: tab bar is not showed.

I wrote

```
// prepareForSegue in view controller 1, 
let upcoming = segue.destinationViewController as! viewcontroller3
upcoming.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true

// prepareForSegue in view controller 3,
let upcoming = segue.destinationViewController as! viewcontroller2
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
```

When I go to view controller 3 from view controller 1, tab bar is not showed. Then, I go to view controller 2 from view controller 3, tab bar is showed. **But when I tap back in view controller 2, tab bar is showed in view controller 3.** `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` does not make sense to me. But, I couldn't figure what I should do to fix that. Any suggestions? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This might help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29706302/905425

Comment: I can't understand objective c. Is it created a new function as I saw return?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**: [That](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6751438/905425) solved the problem.

It makes sense that the tab bar is appearing because when going clicking back from VC2 to VC3, nothing is telling VC3 to hide its Tab Bar.

I think you have 2 solutions here (but haven't tested any):

1. You can try doing something like [this guy did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31436981/905425). He added the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed logic in BackButtonPressed Handler.
2. In VC3, do `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true` in `ViewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6751438/5737856
The one you gave me solved my problem. Thanks man

Comment: Great, will update the answer. Glad it worked for you!

Comment: By the way, I followed the first answer, not the second answer. I still can't understand the second one. HAHA

Comment: Hahaha yes, I tried to make sense out of it, but couldn't too :)

Comment: Haha. I got another question but still related to hidesBottomBarWhenPushed. It is so confused, would you mind to take a look on my question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427102/hide-tab-bar-when-push-and-show-tab-bar-when-back-swift

Answer (score 13):

The way to hide the tab bar is - In the place where you are pushing the next view controller do that:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controllerToPush, animated: true) 
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
```

This will make sure the tab bar is hidden for the pushed view and when you pop back the bar will show again. No back button logic, no viewDidLoad or similar, nothing else. This should be enough.

The same should work for objective-c

Now ( 21/02/2018 ) you can also **check the option** in the **Storyboard** **for each controller that you do not want to show the bottom bar**. This will help clean up the code and you do not need to set anything in the controller that you are pushing from.[image]

Comment: Property should be set on the controller that is about to be pushed as follows 

controllerToPush.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controllerToPush, animated: true)

Comment: @btomtom5 My example actually works perfectly, this was intentionally placed in the controller that is pushing

Comment: Hmmm. But the view controller that is on the top of the nav controller stack is the one that determines whether the bottom bar is shown or not. The viewcontroller that is adding the child vc to the navcontroller shouldn't have any effect on whether the bottom bar is shown or not.

Answer (score 3):

@stan has almost the right answer. As he mentioned, you want to set to set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` if you want the bottom bar to be hidden. However, you should set it on the controller to be pushed as follows.

```
controllerToPush.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controllerToPush, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` in the controller that you want to hide.

For hide all controllers put into `prepare for segue`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    segue.destination.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}
```