# How to implement both UIViewController stack behaviour

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I noticed that WhatsApp has a somewhat neat navigation behaviour on their iOS app. See the following:

## [image]

There are two navigation stack behaviour here:

1. `UINavigationController` as a child of `UITabBarController`
2. `UITabBarController` as a child of `UINavigationController`

How to achieve both of this at the same time, just like WhatsApp? Does it uses a custom `UINavigationController`?

Currently my implementation only does number 2 and not number 1. I do know that to do number 1 I have to make the `UINavigationController` as a child of `UITabBarController`, but I will lose number 2.

However if I implemented both, I will get weird result where I get two navigation bar, like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you give, it looks like they have a `UITabBarController` as the root view controller.  Settings is a view controller inside a navigation controller.

When you tap **Data & Storage**, it pushes another view controller on to the Settings nav controller's stack.

When you press **Help** it does the same - but the tab bar is hidden when the Help view controller is pushed on the stack.

See [hide / show tab bar when push / back. swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427102/hide-show-tab-bar-when-push-back-swift/46234232#46234232) for some ways to do this

Comment: Tested and works just like WhatsApp! I knew about `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` but thought it (the tab bar) would do a slide down animation and not as the original push animation, so I bailed it . I have to do more testing on the hierarchy of the navigation stack for this implementation, and make this as a subclass of `UIViewController`.