# Safe Area bottom layout issue with interactivePopGesture

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios11

[image]

we have used default tabbarcontroller. Tabbar rootViewController display tabbar and other viewcontroller hidden tabbar.The bottom layout of safearea not update hight when we use interactivePopGesture. All other case its working fine

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if navigationController?.viewControllers[0] == self {
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false

    } else {
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set the interactivePopGesture Delegate and handle hiding the tabbar.

Comment: we have already manage of hiding tabbar in viewWillAppear method

Comment: I agree, can you check if it is getting triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// issue is in your Tabbar related view controller Properties

[image]

Follow Below steps:

1) selected your tabbar prfile viewcontroller

2) disable Hide Bottom bar on Push

3) enable Hide Bottom bar on Push when you push on other view controller

Comment: Yes its working, When we need to display tabbar then we need to disable Hide Bottom bar on Push and rest of other viewcontroller we need to set enable Hide Bottom bar on Push. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
// i was solved this issue like that in appdelegate when iam check user already login then i will remove removeGestureRecognizer from view
 let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let loginPageView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomTabVCID") as! CustomTabVC
            let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
            rootViewController.view.removeGestureRecognizer(rootViewController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!)
            rootViewController.pushViewController(loginPageView, animated: true)

// for bottom bar
    // Use this [![enter image description here][1]][1]
    // add this line when you navigate to a ViewController hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: VC_IDENTIFIER) as! YourViewController
        vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
     navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    // hope its work for you

    or try with Main StoryBoard!
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiVrj.png
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiVrj.png applied but getting same issue

When we pushed to viewcontroller its working fine but when try pop using interactivePopGesture and release interactivePopGesture gesture that time this issue occure

Comment: add navigation Controller on Both Controllers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427102/hide-show-tab-bar-when-push-back-swift
// check this out

Comment: above link solution is for tabbar hide show but my problem is tabbar hight when user  try interactivePopGesture and release it without pop to preview controller

Comment: why not remove popGesture on your View Controller ?

Comment: PopGesture removing is not a proper solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189815/discussion-between-sukhwinder-singh-and-ishwar-lal-janwa).